# Deleting elements from a binary search tree

Tags: java

I am currently writing a method that removes a given value from a binary search tree. However when I call it, it deletes the said value but then duplicates every other value. I have no idea why. Please tell me what is wrong.
There are two methods, one that find the elements, and the other that deletes it. 
Here is the one that finds that element...

```
public static TreeNode delete(TreeNode t, Comparable x, TreeDisplay display)
{
    if( x.compareTo(t.getValue()) > 0)
        {
             display.visit(t);

             t.setRight(delete( t.getRight(), x, display));

    }
    else if ( x.compareTo(t.getValue()) < 0)
    {
        display.visit(t);

        t.setLeft(delete(t.getLeft(), x, display));
    }
    else
    {
        t = deleteNode(t, display);
    }

    return t;
```

This is the method that deletes the value

```
private static TreeNode deleteNode(TreeNode t, TreeDisplay display)
  {

    if (t.getRight()!=null)
    {
        TreeNode right = t.getRight();
        TreeNode max = (TreeNode)TreeUtil.leftmost(right);
        TreeNode previous = null;
        while ( right.getLeft()!=null&&right.getLeft().getLeft()!=null)
        {
            right = right.getLeft();
        }
        t.setValue(max.getValue());
        if ( max.getRight()==null)
        {
            right.setLeft(null);
        }
        else
        {
            right.setLeft(max.getRight());
        }
    }
    else if (t.getLeft() !=null)
    {
        TreeNode left = t.getLeft();
        TreeNode max = (TreeNode)TreeUtil.rightmost(left);
        while(left.getRight()!=null &&left.getRight().getRight()!=null)
        {
            left = left.getRight();
        }
        t.setValue(max.getValue());
        if ( max.getLeft()==null)
        {
            left.setRight(null);
        }
        else
        {
            left.setRight(max.getLeft());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        t = null;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This kind of thing is where a debugger comes in handy. You can step through the execution of your code and see what it is actually doing wrong.  Also in deleteNode, you aren't setting a new value to be returned.  You return t, but t is never modified.  e.g. there should be ```t = t.getLeft()``` somewhere.

Comment: Right off the bat it looks like you're needlessly making this too complex. Get the appropriate node, looks like you know how to do that. Then, just delete maxLeft or minRight's node. Looks like too many checks and changes for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

> ...it deletes the said value but then duplicates every other value. I have no idea why. Please tell me what is wrong.

It's because you're returning the deleted node from `deleteNode()`, and in the first method `delete()`, your calls to `setRight()` and `setLeft()` are setting every traversed element to the deleted element as the recursion unwinds back up the tree.